# How will I Convert this code to a ternary operator?

Tags: java

How will I Convert this code

```
    if(a>b)
    {
        x=a; y=b;
    }
    else
    {
        x=b; y=a;
    }
```

to a ternary operator?

Comment: Simple! read about ternary operator  https://alvinalexander.com/java/edu/pj/pj010018
we will not do your homework

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html

Answer (score 0):

Quick Cross-Question in the answer is, Why do you want to do that?
If you really want to assign those values inside of a ternary operator condition result, you can simply make the `x` and `y` variables global variables and call a method to pass your values inside the params. let me show with an example.

```
a > b ? SetXY(a, b) : SetXY(b, a);
```

**PS:** The code line above was not tested before submitting here but it was actually to clear the idea of how to achieve the thing above.